# Proving a norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm proving that, in every normed space, $$ \left\|\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right\|^{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\|y\|^{2} $$ holds. I've tried expanding the left term, obtaining $$\left\|\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right\|^{2} \leq (1/2)(\|x\|^2 + 2\|x\|\|y\| + \|y\|^2) $$ by triangle inequality, but I can't get rid of the $2\|x\|\|y\|$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: when you expand the left term you should get a leading $1/4$ instead of $1/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we look at the inequality $\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|^2 \le \frac{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}{2}$, something that comes to mind is that this particular inequality would be an instance of the *convexity* of the function $\phi(v)=\|v\|^2$. Recall a real-valued function $\phi:V\to\mathbb R$ on a vector space $V$ is **convex** if $\phi$ respects convex combinations in the sense $\phi(rv_1 + sv_2)\le r\phi(v_1)+s\phi(v_2)$ for all $v_1,v_2\in V$, and all $0\le r, s\le 1$ satisfying $r + s = 1$.

If we can show that $\phi(x) = \|x\|^2$ is convex, then we are done. Here is a useful lemma to show this, whose proof I leave to you.

**Lemma.** If $\psi:V\to\mathbb R$ is convex, and $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is an increasing convex function, then $f\circ \psi:V\to\mathbb R$ is convex.

Comment: Every norm satisfies $$\|x+y\|^2 \le (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2=\|x\|^2 + 2\|x\|\|y\| + \|y\|^2\le 2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2$$ Divide by $4$ and you are done. No inner product is needed for the first inequality and equality.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The lemma simply isn't true as stated- additional assumptions are required to ensure that the composition of convex functions is convex.

Comment: @BrianBorchers That's right. Function $f$ should be nondecreasing or $\psi $ linear. Fortunately  $x\to x^2 $ is nondecreasing for $x\ge 0.$

Comment: @BrianBorchers: updated!